# Python, suggestion for an return value design

Tags: python

The question is vague because the problem is to abuse Python for a good cause.
Suppose i have python as program input:

```
scf() # produces F,C that are somehow available globally
ci() # uses F,C
```

question is, can `scf` modify the module of the caller?

and second case:

```
F,C = scf() # F,C are not set globally.
```

So basically either capture value (x)or set it globally.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes me ill to share this, but in CPython you can alter the stack frame:

```
import sys
def scf():
    frame = sys._getframe(1) #caller's frame (probably)
    frame.f_globals['F'] = 'F' #add/overwrite globals
    frame.f_globals['C'] = 'C'

def ci():
    print F, C

scf()
ci() # prints 'F C'
```

However, why do you need to invisibly alter the namespace of the caller? This reeks of bad design. `scf()` should return things and `ci()` should accept those things as arguments. If you share more about what you are doing perhaps we can suggest better approaches.

### Update

So you're trying to maintain some state between externally-executed strings which are Python programs. This is trivial to do in Python: simply keep an explicit locals and globals namespace and pass it between invocations of [`exec` and friends](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval).

```
s1 = """
foo = 'bar'
"""

s2 = """
def myImpureFunction():
    global foo
    foo = 1
myImpureFunction()
"""

lvars, gvars = {}, {}

exec s1 in lvars, gvars
print gvars
exec s2 in lvars, gvars
print gvars
```

Perhaps to keep *some* semblance of sanity you can guarantee to your users that one special var will be persisted between runs:

```
s1 = """
stash.foo = 'bar'
"""

s2 = """
def myImpureFunction():
    stash.foo = 'foo'
myImpureFunction()
"""

from types import ModuleType

lvars = {'stash': ModuleType('stash')}

exec s1 in lvars
print lvars['stash'].foo
exec s2 in lvars
print lvars['stash'].foo
```

Comment: Well the idea is to use Py as input language and be able to do default execution (propagate vars up automagically) or explicitly require ci arguments if returns were captured explicitly

Comment: What do you mean by "use Py as input language"?

Comment: basically I have a complicated input, with many options and dependent function.  At the same time I want ability to script arbitrarily.  Hence python script is actually a (c++) program input

Comment: I think you should expand your question with much more detail, but it sounds like you're trying to embed a Python runtime in your program? If so, [there's a manual for that](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html).  If you just want to evaluate some Python strings use [`exec`, `eval` and friends](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) and provide them with locals and globals. (Noting that this is completely insecure, despite the superficial resemblance to sandboxing.)

Comment: Yes, I do have Python embedded, but the question is how to make it easier for user to use.  populating parent's scope makes things rather convinient.

Comment: On the contrary, surprise global mutation of state sounds *much harder* to use!

Comment: perhaps I could have a "magic" variable in parent that would have variables passed up?  I know it is bad, but it would make things easier on users

Comment: @Anycorn, I added an example using `exec` and an explicit namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I usually approach this problem by creating an Object Pool similar to the following

```
>>> class Pool:
    from collections import namedtuple, defaultdict, OrderedDict
    namespace = defaultdict(OrderedDict)
    @staticmethod
    def add(ns='default', **kwargs):
        Pool.namespace[ns].update(kwargs)
    @staticmethod
    def pop(ns='default', *args):
        return [Pool.namespace[ns].pop(k) for k in args]
    @staticmethod
    def remove(ns):
        if ns == 'default':
            raise AttributeError
        del Pool.namespace[ns]
    @staticmethod
    def get(ns='default', **kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            return namedtuple(ns,kwargs.keys())(Pool.namespace[ns][k] for k in kwargs)
        else:

            return namedtuple(ns,Pool.namespace[ns].keys())(*Pool.namespace[ns].values())
    @staticmethod
    def ns():
        return Pool.namespace.keys()
    @staticmethod
    def purge():
        Pool.namespace = defaultdict(OrderedDict)


>>> Pool.add('NS1',F=10,G=20)
>>> Pool.add('NS2',A=1,B=2)
>>> Pool.pop('NS1')
[]
>>> Pool.pop('NS1','F')
[10]
>>> Pool.get('NS1')
NS1(G=20)
>>> Pool.add(X=100,Y=200)
>>> Pool.ns()
['', 'NS1', 'NS2']
>>> Pool.remove('NS1')
>>> Pool.ns()
['', 'NS2']

>>> def sci():
    Pool.add("sci",F=20,G=30)


>>> def ci():
    ns_sci = Pool.get("sci")
    print ns_sci.F, ns_sci.G


>>> sci()
>>> ci()
20 30
>>>
```

You can now use this across functions or modules without polluting the global namespace. You can also distribute it across namespace so multiple namespace can coexist.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class:

```
class A(object):
    def scf(self):
        self.F = 10
        self.C = 20
    def ci(self):
        print self.F, self.C
```

**Update:**

or a "standalone" class:

```
class B(object):
    @staticmethod
    def scf():
        B.F = 10
        B.C = 20
    @staticmethod
    def ci():
        print B.F, B.C

B.scf()
B.ci()
```

Comment: hmm ... can i make class members as default arguments?